# how to know when does Amazon cloudfront is deployed, Is there any way for this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

My question is just what I wrote in the title. I'm trying to create a cdn in amazon cloud front through its sdk. Now the problem is that, it took some time to deploy the complete setup. One way to solve this problem is to continuously hit on the cloudfront to know its deployment status,  but is there any other way to do that, like it sends a notification to my application on a specific url.I'm using amazon's java sdk for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned that you are using AWS Java SDK, I think you can use the `Class GetDistributionResult`.

This class has a method called `getDistribution()` which you can use along with `getStatus()` which will give you response with the current status of the distribution. Now you can just check like this

```
if (status.equals("Deployed")) 
{
  send a notification to my application on a specific URL
}
```

For more information on [GetDistributionResult](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudfront/model/Distribution.html)

Comment: AWS cf takes time to get deployed. We get the  GetDistributionResult immediately. In this case the status will be "deploying". Therefore the status need to be check repeatedly and that's what I dont want to do.